# Error "emit without supply or react" when tapping IO::Notifications

Tags: concurrency, raku

These nested supplies cause an error, but apparently only if the internal supply is IO::Notification. It does not seem to be a problem for any other supply:

```
my $supply = IO::Notification.watch-path( "/var/log/syslog" );

my $parsed = supply {
    $supply.tap: -> $v {
        emit( { Seen => $v.event }  );
        CATCH {
            default {
                $*ERR.say: .message;
            }
        }
    }
}

$parsed.tap( -> $v { say $v });

sleep 40;
```

This is the error emitted:

```
emit without supply or react
emit without supply or react
```

(when there's a event that fires the supply). I haven't been able to reproduce it in other kind of nested supplies, but this always fails. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must use `whenever` to subscribe to `$supply`, otherwise the subscription won't be associated with the `supply` block (and so, aside from `emit` not working, also won't get concurrency control, subscription management, and so forth).

```
my $supply = IO::Notification.watch-path( "foo" );

my $parsed = supply {
    # Solution: use `whenever` here
    whenever $supply -> $v {
        emit( { Seen => $v.event }  );
        CATCH {
            default {
                $*ERR.say: .message;
            }
        }
    }
}

$parsed.tap( -> $v { say $v });

sleep 40;
```

(About it perhaps sometimes working out: if you subscribe to something that produces values synchronously after tapping, the `emit` handler would be in dynamic scope of the setup phase of the `supply` block, so in that case it may appear to work.)

Comment: That's because taps happen in a different lexical environment? Should we maybe document that?

Comment: Because `tap` is the low-level thing and `whenever` is the high-level thing implemented in terms of it. `whenever` doesn't simply pass the body to `tap`; instead, it wraps it up in concurrency control, subscription management, and control exception handlers for `emit` and `done`. Documentation wise, we should guide people towards `supply`/`react`/`whenever` over `tap`.